# The method select(String) in the type Element is not applicable for the arguments (Element)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm getting 3 errors after attempting a suggestion posted by another user in the following SO post:

[Unable to Use Simple JSOUP Example To Parse Website Table Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122596/unable-to-use-simple-jsoup-example-to-parse-website-table-data)

It's my first time building anything using JSoup so any tips/tricks or things I should know are greatly appreciated.

ERRORS:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Elements to Element  
The method select(String) in the type Element is not applicable for the arguments (Element)
tr cannot be resolved to a variable
```

SOURCE:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    final String URL = "http://exampleurl.com";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid");
                Element th = doc.select(tr).first;
                Element firstTh = th.select(th).first();
                title = firstTh.text();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

REVISION 1:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    final String URL = "http://exampleurl.com";
String tr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Elements tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid");
           //     Elements th = doc.select(tr).first;
                Elements th = doc.select(".attribute").first();
                title = firstTh.text();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the javadoc, [`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) returns an `Elements` Object rather than an `Element`.

```
Elements tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid");
```

[`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) accept a `String` literal rather than an Element, so a `String` is required as its parameter. Also methods require parenthesis. As [`first`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first%28%29) is a method - it requires parenthesis

```
Element th = doc.select(".yourattributehere").first();
                             ^              ^----- add parenthesis
                             |--provide valid selector query
```

Comment: That resolved one error (thank you) but I'm still getting 
tr cannot be resolved to a variable
The method select(String) in the type Elements is not applicable for the arguments (Elements) 
 in my compiler

Comment: Does my revision above look correct? (I'm still getting 2 errors)

Description Resource Path Location Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Element to Elements MainActivity.java /test/src/com/example/test line 55 Java Problem
firstTh cannot be resolved MainActivity.java /test/src/com/example/test line 56 Java Problem

Comment: No don't put `.attribute` in literally, put in whatever attribute you're looking for. Also those compile errors tell you what's gone wrong, tiny update...